# Am I using IF COUNTA the correct way?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using a IF COUNTA to count the number of spaces which contains data and according to that amount of cells containing data I want to categorize them in different zones.

[image: Pen Pulling image]

This is my current sheet I am using. Block A is the random Pen teams draw and according to that they are inserted into the space next to their pen. I use VLOOKUP for every cell (TEAM, NAME & SURNAME) to find the pen and then pulls data from that pen which gives me the person's team, name and surname.

[image: Team Entry image]

Here is where teams are inserted and the random pens are pulled. In the example they all pulled 1 - 16 just for easier test.

Using image one I reference the table name "Zone" for help: What I currently have inside that cell is the following...

```
=IF(COUNTA($B$2:$B$21)<=13,"Zone A",IF(COUNTA($B$2:$B$21)*13>=20,"Zone B","Test Again"))
```

So what I am trying to say here in my mind is that if COUNTA counts 13 or less then it should mark them "Zone A", else if COUNTA counts more than 13 or equal to 20 it should mark them "Zone B". So this works like that because there are 200 entries but I want the first 13 to be marked "Zone A" and everything else after 13 should be "Zone B". How do I formulate such a scenario?

In Cells B1:D21 I am using the following VLOOKUP formula...

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP([@[Pen Pulled]],'Team Entry'!$A$3:$G$35, 2, FALSE)), "",VLOOKUP([@[Pen Pulled]],'Team Entry'!$A$3:$G$35, 2, FALSE))
```

This is to not show NA when someone have not yet pulled the next pin.

Comment: I hope someone can help me hehe!

Answer (score -1):

i'm not exactly sure why u have this
**IF(COUNTA($B$2:$B$21)*13>=20**
that is asking if the count **times** 13 is => 20
Anything more than 13 would include 20 so I would think
***IF(COUNTA($B$2:$B$21)>13***
would give u what u r defining.